# What does #= mean in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I recently saw a program in Prolog using the predicate #=/2. I looked this up on [the SWI prolog website](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%23%3D%20/%202) where they defined it as

> The arithmetic expression X equals Y. When reasoning over integers, replace is/2 by #=/2 to obtain more general relations.

What I don't understand about this is how #=/2 can be more 'general' since it is *only* for integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation [entry page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd):

> They implement *pure relations* between integer *expressions* and can be used in *all directions*

Just an example:

```
?- X+3 #= X*2.
X = 3.
```

Looks simple, but actually it's rather difficult to obtain such result within conventional arithmetic expression evaluation.

```
?- X+3 is X*2.
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

From the [is](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2)/2 page, you can see the signature

```
-Number is +Expr
```

where `+Expr` means it *must* be ground.

Also, the left argument of is/2 actually *should* be atomic:

```
?- 3+3 is 3*2.
false.
```

despite we *know* the above statement should be true...

A note: the name CLP(FD) is a bit an 'understatement', as pointed out by @false, could be named CLP(Z), since finiteness of domain can often be relaxed.